# Adding a default scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want default scope to be applied **only** to `index` action in a model.

I'm adding `default_scope` to the model as such:

```
default_scope { where(:status => "Active") }
```

and I can use `unscope` in the other actions (i.e, `show`, `edit`, `update` and `delete`) as such:

```
@beacon = Beacon.where(id: params[:id]).unscope(where: :status).first
```

instead of:

```
@beacon = Beacon.find(params[:id]
```

to override the behavior of the default scope.

Is there any **ActiveAdmin** or **Rails** method to apply the **default scope** **only** to `index`?

I'm using ActiveAdmin.

I may add more actions in the future, only to which I need to apply the default scope, so I'm looking for a **shorter and compact solution**.

Comment: Why don't you just apply this scope in index action?

Comment: @Ilya I may add more actions in the future where i need to apply the default scope to those actions only, so I'm looking  for a shorter solution.

Comment: The neatest way I can think of would be to have a separate 'collection' method in your controller, with a before action that applies the scope you want to that collection for the given actions. Given the model doesn't know which controller action it's in I don't see a way to do it directly from the model file.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for your comment. I ended up considering your approach and the end result is a **neat and compact solution** :)

Comment: No worries - was going to write up something like that but I have my boss in the office with me today so had to wait until lunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I was hoping there could be a **simple helper**, which I could use to apply the *default scope* only to **certain actions**. But instead, I ended up adding a `before_action`, which will fetch the `unscoped` records for only certain actions.

```
before_action :set_unscoped_beacon_variables, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def set_unscoped_beacon_variables
  @beacons = Beacon.unscope(where: :status)
  @beacon = Beacon.where(id: params[:id]).unscope(where: :status).first
end
```

This way, I can add more such actions to `before_action` list and for the remaining actions (where the default scope is required), the `default_scope` will take care!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a collection called `@scoped` or similar for this?

For example:

```
ACTIONS_WITH_DEFAULT_SCOPE = ['index']

before_action :set_scoped_collection

...

def set_scoped_collection
  @scoped = if action_name.in?(ACTIONS_WITH_DEFAULT_SCOPE)
    Beacon.where(status: "Active")
  else
    Beacon.all
  end
end

# or the otherway round, using `unscope`
def set_scoped_collection
  @scoped = if action_name.in?(ACTIONS_WITH_DEFAULT_SCOPE)
    Beacon.all
  else
    Beacon.unscope(where: :status)
  end
end
```

Seems a workable solution - how does that fit with your requirements?